# Groupby pandas throwing ValueError: Grouper and axis must be same length

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have csv below

```
ID,PR_No,PMO,PRO,REV,COST
111,111,AB,MA,2575,2575
111,111,AB,MA,-1137,-1137
112,112,CD,KB,1134,3334
111,111,AB,MA,100,100
```

Output as below

```
ID,PR_No,PMO,PRO,REV,COST
111,111,AB,MA,1538,1538
112,112,CD,KB,1134,3334
```

1538=2575-1137+100

My code is throwing values error

```
df_n = df.groupby([['ID','PR_No','PMO','PRO']]).agg({'REV':sum,'COST':sum})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove nested `[]` for list of columns names:

```
df_n = df.groupby(['ID','PR_No','PMO','PRO']).agg({'REV':sum,'COST':sum})
print (df_n)
                    REV  COST
ID  PR_No PMO PRO            
111 111   AB  MA   1538  1538
112 112   CD  KB   1134  3334
```

Because same aggregate function is possible create list after groupby with `.sum`:

```
df_n = df.groupby(['ID','PR_No','PMO','PRO'])['REV','COST'].sum()
```

---

> ValueError: Grouper and axis must be same length

What does it mean?

If run with sample data it working, because length of nested list is same like length of sample data:

```
df_n = df.groupby([['ID','PR_No','PMO','PRO']]).agg({'REV':sum,'COST':sum})
print (df_n)
        REV  COST
ID     2575  2575
PMO    1134  3334
PRO     100   100
PR_No -1137 -1137
```

If create list with duplicates it aggregate sample data:

```
df_n = df.groupby([['ID','ID','PRO','PRO']]).agg({'REV':sum,'COST':sum})
print (df_n)
      REV  COST
ID   1438  1438
PRO  1234  3434
```

But if length is different it failed:

```
print (df)
    ID  PR_No PMO PRO   REV  COST
0  111    111  AB  MA  2575  2575
1  111    111  AB  MA -1137 -1137
2  112    112  CD  KB  1134  3334
3  111    111  AB  MA   100   100
4  111    111  AB  MA   100   100 <- added new row

df_n = df.groupby([['ID','ID','PRO','PRO']]).agg({'REV':sum,'COST':sum})
print (df_n)
```

> ValueError: Grouper and axis must be same length

Answer (score -1):

Try with some agg or sum function it will work...

```
df_n = df.groupby([......])[....].sum()
```